# adfs login authentication on android application

Tags: java, android, adfs

I was working on an android application but for the sign in i need to sign in using **ADFS**. I have tried using Facebook and Twitter sign in and it worked but there is no official documentation to integrate through **ADFS**. Can anyone help me on the same?

Answer (score 2):

Search for Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for Android. This uses OAuth to get JWT tokens for your web services.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn633593.aspx

Thanks //Sam (@MrADFS)